# JS Omniture Video Tracking / Brightcove

Tags: javascript, html5-video, tracking, adobe-analytics, brightcove

I'm having an issue with manually tracking video with Omniture. I have included the `s.loadModule("Media");` and the following config:

```
/*Configure Media Module Functions */
s.Media.autoTrack= false;
s.Media.trackMilestones="50";
s.Media.playerName="brightcove";
s.Media.segmentByMilestones = true;
s.Media.trackUsingContextData = true;
s.Media.trackVars="events,prop9,eVar9,prop11,eVar11,prop12,eVar12,prop13,eVar13, prop14, eVar14, prop32, eVar34";
s.Media.trackEvents="event8,event11,event12";
s.Media.contextDataMapping = {
    "a.media.name":"eVar2,prop2",
    "a.media.segment":"eVar3",
    "a.contentType":"eVar1",
    "a.media.timePlayed":"event3",
    "a.media.view":"event11",
    "a.media.segmentView":"event8",
    "a.media.complete":"event12",
    "a.media.milestones":{
        50:"event8"
    }
}
```

I'm using the Brightcove SmartPlayer API in order to fire off the Omniture calls onMediaBegin, onMediaComplete and manually checking for the 50% playback milestone onMediaProgress.

```
onMediaBeginFired : function(evt) {
   s.Media.open('my_vid',320,'brightcove');
   s.Media.play('my_vid',0);
}
```

I get the follow JS error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'open'
```

I can see the s.Media object in console but I'm not sure why the s.Media object doesn't have any of the methods I need like, 'open', 'play', 'close'???

I can still make s.t() or s.tl() calls so I know it has something to do with the Media module or I'm missing something within the config process.

Note: We no longer want to use the Brightcove Flash plugin because it doesn't report on mobile devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a race condition that needed to be worked out.

Comment: I didn't know you could answer your own question and qualify that as a valid answer. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the race condition was? We're having similar issues.

Comment: @Christian I'm no longer working on that project but I think it was related to requirejs and when something was "ready". If I remember correctly I had some code on the page where the player was rendered and some in another requirejs module. That's about all I can recall, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for getting back anyway @pjdicke.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a lot easier to integrate the following:

http://video.marijka.com/brightcove-smart-module/

I didn't find about it until today and was released after your original post but I figured it would help other users get their answer.

Comment: Thanks for submitting an answer. I forgot to close this issue but I think I was fighting a race condition in my code.